# How to add multiple intervals to Date_Add

Tags: mysql, date, intervals

I want to add 2 months and 2 years to the current date but for some reason i cannot get it to work.

```
 Select DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH, INTERVAL 2 YEAR);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `date_add()` twice:

```
Select DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH), INTERVAL 2 YEAR);
```

Or once:

```
Select DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 MONTH);
```

Answer (score 12):

You could also just use addition

```
SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 2 YEAR + INTERVAL 2 MONTH
```